# What if two python packages have different versions of package dependencies?

Tags: python, package, dependency-management

I'm confused about python dependencies.

- Use **C package version 1.0** in **A package**
- Use **C package version 2.0** in **B package**

In the case below, the **C** will have **2 different versions** installed? Or do **A** and **B** both use **C version 2.0**?

Comment: Only one version will be installed. the newest one. But Package A may be not running with the new version of C.

Comment: The first thing to check would be if version 2.0 is backwards compatible with 1.0, because if it is, you only need 2.0 (and for most packages, this will be the case for most functionality, if not all. If it isn't and the packages you absolutely need to use rely on different and incompatible versions of the package, and there's no versions of A and B that you can use that can use the same version of C, the options I see are either to run A and B independently and connect applications, or take the older version of C and rebuild and import it as differently named package (if the license allows)

Comment: (that is assuming you can then change A to use the renamed version, of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question depends on the package manager you use and how it resolves dependency conflicts. If you're using the standard package manager (`pip`), then it should let you know if this type of error occurs. The way `pip` works is by a process known as ["backtracking"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/#backtracking), which essentially works "backwards" from the latest version to find the most recent version that a package is compatible with. In the event that two packages ask for conflicting versions of another package, you get what's known as a [`ResolutionImpossible` error](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts), which will cancel the installation process. This can generally only be resolved by either forcing `pip` to choose a specific version or updating the `requirements.txt` files of the packages you're trying to install. `conda` works in a similar way, though it will often resort to installing the latest version and then warning you instead of the error that `pip` throws out.